# php file size validation

Tags: php, validation, if-statement

I would like to create in php file size validation  for every single file. I used for loop to add attachments,  and then  created  condition to check file, but it's not working. There's no error,  but it send mail with oversized attachment, instead of stop. Without the size validation  part, it sends mail without any problems.

For sending I used php mailer.

```php
   <?php
//Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
//These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

//Load Composer's autoloader
require 'autoload.php';

//Create an instance; passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$honeypot = $_POST['honey'];
$user_name = $_POST['name'];
$user_email = $_POST['email'];
$user_message = $_POST['message'];
$user_phone = $_POST['phone'];
$honeypot = trim($_POST["honey"]);
$max_size = 2 * 1024 * 1204; //2mb
$attachment = $_FILES['uploaded-file'];

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {


    if(!empty($honeypot)) {
        echo "NO SPAM!"; 
        exit;
      }    else {

        $mail = new PHPMailer; //From email address and name 
        $mail->isMail(); 
        $mail->From = $user_email;
        $mail->addAddress("jaroslaw.mor@gmail.com");
        $mail->isHTML(true); 
        $mail->Subject = "Zapytanie ze strony www"; 
        $mail->Body = "Telefon:$user_phone<br><br>Treść wiadomośći:<br>$user_message";
        $mail->AltBody = "Telefon:$user_phone\n$content"; 
        
        
        if(isset($attachment)) {

            for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['uploaded-file']['name']); $i++) {
                if ($_FILES['uploaded-file']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) continue;
                $file_TmpName = $_FILES['uploaded-file']["tmp_name"][$i]; 
                $file_name = $_FILES['uploaded-file']["name"][$i];  

                if($_FILES['uploaded-file']["name"][$i];  > $max_size) {
                    echo "file is too big";
                    die();
}
                 
                else{
                 move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName,  "uploads/" . $filename);
                 $mail-> AddAttachment("uploads/". $filename);
                                                                }      
            }//for
        }//isset

        if(!$mail->send()) {
            echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
           exit();
      } 
      
              else {
              header("Location: sent.html");
                             
                 exit();

      }//if send else

}//honey else end

}//post end
```

I have rebuilt my code a bit, and also complied with comments/clues.

But there's still the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a copy paste error

```php
$_FILES['uploaded-file']["name"]['size'][$i]
```

According to the PHP [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php), size is under `$_FILES['uploaded-file']` and *not* `$_FILES['uploaded-file']['name']`. See @yuxufabio's comment.

And the `if (isset($attachments))` check is a bit weird. It'll always return an array (meaning true) even if it's empty. What you probably mean is if the form variable itself is set or not

```php
if (isset($_FILES['uploaded-file'])) {
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['uploaded-file']['name']); $i++) {
```

Lastly, you should be checking if there's an error, as the upload is not garuanteed to work at the fault of the client, such as an empty file or a network error

```php
if ($_FILES['uploaded-file']['error'][$i] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) continue;
...
if ($_FILES['uploaded-file']['size'][$i] > $maxsize) {
...
```

Comment: I complied with the clues, but there's still the same problem -  when  attachment is too big it send email  without attachment instead of stop. I Updated code form 1st post.

Comment: @Jaro Hi again, I'm sorry, I meant `['error'][$i]` and not `['error']` (it even tripped me up.) I have edited my answer. Please try again and let me know if that fixes it.

Comment: Thx a lot,,  now validation works without any problem. One more time, really big thx U!

Answer (score 1):

What I can see here is that you used the "move_upload_file" way earlier before you checked for the file size. And that means the file will be uploaded before checking to see if it's bigger or not. It should be something like this;

```
if( $_FILES['uploaded-file']["name"]['size'][$i] > $maxsize ) {

            echo "file is too big";
            die();
        }else{
         move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName,  "uploads/" . $filename);
         $mail-> AddAttachment("uploads/". $filename);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan - It's a copy paste error. It should be $_FILES['uploaded-file']["name"][$i]. I think with the $attachement, he justed wanted to make sure the user has selected a file. "if(getimagesize($_FILES['uploaded-file']["tmp_name"][$i]))" may be used instead if it is an image file